# Typescript Reflection api

Tags: javascript, typescript, рефлексия, декоратор

я пытаюсь задать метаданные для свойства класса

```
export class Info{
  @Column({type: 1}) location: string;
  @Column({type: 6}) description: string;
}
```

Декаратор

```
export const Column = (params: any) => {
  return <T>(target: T, key: keyof T) => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(key, params, target);
  }
};
```

получение данных

```
function getDecorators(target: any) {
  // get info about keys that used in current property
  const decorators: any[] = Reflect.getMetadataKeys(target);
  console.log(decorators);
}



 let info: Info= new Info();
  getDecorators(info);
```

Но получаю только список имен свойства класса а параметры которые передал в декоратор нет.

```
[
  'location',
  'description',
]
```

Как их получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы в качестве ключа (`metadataKey`) используете название свойства. `Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, metadataValue, target);` этот метод возвращет только ключи (в вашем случае названия свойств.

Т.е. у вас получается, что-то похожее на:

```
location = { type: 1 }
description = { type: 1 }
```

Если вы этого и хотели, то можете использовать `Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, target);` чтобы получить значение, например:

```
Reflect.getMetadata("location", target); // { type: 1 }
```

Если же вы хотите использовать `type` как ключ, то можно использовать что-то такое:

```
export const Column = (params: any) => {
    return <T>(target: T, key: any) => {
        for (const prop in params) {
            Reflect.defineMetadata(prop, params[prop], target, key);
        }
    }
};

Reflect.getMetadata("type", target, "location"); // 1
Reflect.getMetadata("type", target, "description"); // 6
```

Comment: можете написать код что бы поулчить что то типа такова
[ {location: { type: 1 }},
{description: { type: 6 }}] не совсем понимаю

Comment: разобрался спасибо